# C# XMLDocument returning a string from a case insensitive search

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following method to return the value of an attribute that i'm looking for, however I get `Expression Must evaluate to a node-set`

my path is this `/Message` and my attribute is `sequence`

If just do this

```
XmlNode mytestNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode(xPath);
string attributec = mytestNode.Attributes[attribute].Value;
```

I get the value i want but the `attribute name` doesn't come back in the same case all the time

here is my method

```
 public static string xmlNode_GetValue_From_Attribute(XmlDocument xDoc, string xPath, string attribute)
        {

            return xDoc.SelectSingleNode(xPath + "/@" + "[translate(" + attribute + ", ‘ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ’, ‘abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz’)").Value;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your string concatenation code produces expression in the following form, which is not a valid XPath expression i.e `@` is not a valid node selector, missing quotes around `attribute` variable value, missing `]` at the end :

```
/@[translate(
    your attribute variable value, 
    'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 
    'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
)
```

If I understand this correctly, you want to produce the following XPath expression :

```
/@*[
    translate(
        name(), 
        'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 
        'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    ) = 'your attribute variable value'
]
```

The above returns attributes where attribute name equals `attribute` variable value, case-insensitive. So the corresponding C# code should be :

```
string attributeQuery = @"/@*[
    translate(
        name(), 
        'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 
        'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    ) = '{0}'
]";
attributeQuery = string.Format(attributeQuery, attribute.ToLower());
return xDoc.SelectSingleNode(xPath + attributeQuery).Value;
```

<sub>NB: All XPath above are wrapped into lines only to make it (hopefully) more readable.</sub>